# How do I hardcode a WordPress shortcode into my theme?

Tags: php, themes, shortcode

I am using WooTheme's Canvas theme and would like to "hardcode" in the [post_comments] shortcode into my theme. [post_comments] displays a comment link with comment count (ie Comments 10) in my post. Right now I am inserting the [post_comments] shortcode into my theme's meta "Meta Manager"; however, this is not ideal for me as I have limited control over the placement of where the this shows up in my post. What type of function or such should I be looking for to do this within my .php files?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out do_shortcode(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

```
do_shortcode('[shortcode option1="value1" option2="value2"]');
```

So your example would be:

```
do_shortcode('[post_comments]');
```

What might be easier is to tap into the underlying comment functions:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

```
<p>
  This post currently has
  <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>.
</p>
```

You can also use `get_comments_number` which returns the value rather than printing it to the screen.

This function however needs to be in the Loop for it to work, however I have a feeling it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But this didn't seem to work. do_shortcode('[post_comments]');      I placed this in my content-post.php file

Comment: Where is that shortcode defined, is it in the Canvas theme?

Comment: Thanks! get_comments_number() is a great solution! I'm just going to add "Comments" text and wrap the number in "()".

Comment: Yes, [post_comments] is defined within theme-shortcodes.php